# Multiple language emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I wanted to know if there's any functionality to determine what language preference a device / PC is set to so we can serve the correct language to the individual?

For example

Preference set to English we would serve the English email

or

preference was set to French we would serve the French version

thanks inadvance

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, the language/country is set in the database of record for each subscriber, not by some sort of device detection.  The email is then scripted to display content based on the subscribers language/country.

There are several ways to go about this in the SFMC platform.  Most of which include a generic template with the multi-lingual content stored in data extensions or content areas.  The data is retrieved with AMPScript in the email, stored variables and included in the email HTML.

Comment: in exact target i have this piece of code to distinguish whether the user is enlgish, german etc. I use it normally in images example: <img src="images/test_%%InternalLanguageCode%%.png"> 

Now i want to do an if statement

if %%InternalLanguageCode%% == en
english content ELSEIF %%InternalLanguageCode%% == de
Show german content.

How can i do that in exact target email template? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Adam says, there is no way to get hold of this preference using information from the device. If you don't know up front what language your subscriber speaks, then it would also be difficult to know which language versions you need to produce in the first place.

I would recommend 2 next steps:

1. Seek to capture language preference prior to communicating to
   your subscribers (easy to say in hindsight, but useful for new
   subscribers) you can then include this in your audience data
   extension or within your subscriber attributes.
2. Include the option to change language preference within all email
   communications, then store this preference either as a subscriber
   attribute or within a Data Extension to be used for future
   communications. This allows you to send your communications initially in English, but all the subscriber to opt for an alternative preference.